# My div box is not wrapping the contents properly when the website display is reduced

Tags: html, css

These are my HTML and CSS file.
So in the color section, the div box does not wrap the contents properly (they overflow?) when the screen is reduced.
I want my color div box to wrap the contents even though the screen is reduced like in every size of screen
How can I fix this?

```css
header {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.heading {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.typography {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.color {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}

.color p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 78px;
}

p.black {
    background:black;
    color: white;
}

p.gray {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}

p.blue {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

p.white {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000000;
    transition: ease-out .2s;
}

.color .btn a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 133px 0 0 0 #000000;
    color: white;
}

.font .btn a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 160px 0 0 0 #000000;
    color: white;
}

.font {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}

.font p {
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.font-pair-head {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.Oswald {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.Quattrocento {
    font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
}

.Raleway {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.Roboto {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.Amatic {
    font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.Josefin {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.Playfair-Display {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.Fauna-One {
    font-family: 'Fauna One', serif;
}

.Alfa-Slab {
    font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
}

.Open-sans {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>My Website Style Guide</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="typography">
            <h1 class="heading">Typography</h1>
            <h1>h1: Main Heading</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Font-weight: 700</li>
                    <li>Font-size: 32px</li>
                    <li>Font-family: </li>
                </ul>
            <h2>h2: Sub Heading</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Font-weight: 700</li>
                    <li>Font-size: 24px</li>
                    <li>Font-family: </li>
                </ul>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Font-weight: 400</li>
                    <li>Font-size: 16px</li>
                    <li>Font-family: </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="color">
            <h1 class="heading">Color</h1>
                <p class="black">black</p>
                <p class="gray">gray</p>
                <p class="white">white</p>
                <p class="blue">blue</p>
            <div class="btn"><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value" target="_blank">See more colors</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="font">
            <h1 class="heading">Font pairs</h1>
            <p><span class="Oswald font-pair-head">Oswald</span> + <span class="Quattrocento font-pair-tail">Quattrocento</span></p>
            <p><span class="Raleway font-pair-head">Raleway</span> + <span class="Roboto font-pair-tail">Roboto</span></p>
            <p><span class="Amatic font-pair-head">Amatic SC</span> + <span class="Josefin font-pair-tail">Josefin Sans</span></p>
            <p><span class="Playfair-Display font-pair-head">Playfair Display</span> + <span class="Fauna-One font-pair-tail">Fauna One</span></p>
            <p><span class="Alfa-Slab font-pair-head">Alfa Slab</span> + <span class="Open-sans font-pair-tail">Open Sans</span></p>
            <div class="btn"><a href="https://www.reliablepsd.com/ultimate-google-font-pairings/">See more font pairs</a></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and if you know, can anybody tell me how to attach files on stack overflow?
Thank you!!

Comment: You can't attach files on StackOverflow. You either provide the necessary code in a runnable code snippet or code block. Alternatively, use an image or external link to JSFiddle or CodePen if you think it's "too much" code to include in a single question.

Comment: @jlee4641: Hi Mate ! There are answers provided SO users for your question. Which ever question you feel is fulfilling you requirement. It is advised to accept that answer. :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers HAPPY CODING

Answer (score -1):

What type of files would you like to attach? You can attach images or run a code snippet

When it comes to the color div, to a fix `height: 300px;`

You might want to change it to `height: auto;` to work on small screens

Comment: It's still not working :( and i just wanna attach the HTML and css file since i don't wanna put all the codes in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to this but I've just learnt about two CSS directives which should wrap the content when reducing the screen, `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Does it help inserting them in your color class?

```
.color {
  /* ...other properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```